# I want to extract information from my text file and save it in a separate file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to extract information from my file and save it in a separate file.

The input file looks like:

```
>Feature NODE_18_1000_cov_1.366138
1 888 CDS
   db_xref COG:COG3385
   inference ab initio prediction:Prodigal:2.6
   inference similar to AA sequence:ISfinder:ISPg4
   locus_tag LFHBJEGH_33517
   product IS4 family transposase ISPg4
>Feature NODE_18222_1000_cov_1.310053
665 330 CDS
   inference ab initio prediction:Prodigal:2.6
   locus_tag LFHBJEGH_33518
   product hypothetical protein
962 675 CDS
   inference ab initio prediction:Prodigal:2.6
   locus_tag LFHBJEGH_335
   product hypothetical protein
>Feature NODE_18194_1000_cov_2.550265
939 187 CDS
   EC_number 1.14.99.46
   db_xref COG:COG2141
   gene rutA_3
   inference ab initio prediction:Prodigal:2.6
   inference similar to AA sequence:UniProtKB:P75898
   locus_tag LFHBJEGH_33480
   product Pyrimidine monooxygenase RutA
```

I want to match the NODE ID (the name after ">") with "locus_tag".
The output I want looks like:

```
Feature NODE_18_1000_cov_1.366138 LFHBJEGH_33517
Feature NODE_18222_1000_cov_1.310053 LFHBJEGH_33518
Feature NODE_18222_1000_cov_1.310053 LFHBJEGH_335
Feature NODE_18194_1000_cov_2.550265 LFHBJEGH_33480
```

Which command would work for this?

Answer (score 1):

with `awk`:

```
awk '/>Feature NODE_/{ nodeId=$0; next } /locus_tag/{ print nodeId, $2 }' infile
```

Comment: This worked very well. I will check the awk command in a detail to check what this command means. Thank you very much for your help!